# How to Mock the value of a variable using unittest which is being used in another python file

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest

I have the following file `constants.py`

```py
# Here all the constants are written
variable_name = False
...
```

The above variable **variable_name** from `constants.py` is being used in another file `b.py`

```py
#b.py

import constants
def func():
   if constants.variable_name:
       """ Do Something """
   else:
       """ Do Something """
```

Here, how can I mock the *variable_name* from `constants.py` to `True` to test the `if` condition of the function `func` using unittest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can patch the variable as follows:

```
import constants
from mock import patch
@patch('constants.variable_name', True)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just need to pre-set the value of a variable you can use the `setUp` method of the test case:

```py
import constants
class test_class(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        constants.variable_name = True
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response, but will it change the value of the actual variable?

Comment: It didn't change the actual value. So, is it like, we mocked the module itself?

Comment: Well, being a global variable, is there something else that changes it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `unittest.mock.patch` to patch the object:

```
from unittest.mock import patch

with patch('constants.variable_name', True):
    func()
```